# CakePHP 2.1 plugin for upload an image

Tags: image, plugins, cakephp-2.1

I am using cakephp 2.1 and developing an application that does upload the images. So I need a plugin that does like

1.Validate an image.
2.Crop the image by custom size.
3.deletes an image file after the entry from database get deleted.

Please suggest me some plugins which include all these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Meio Upload: https://github.com/jrbasso/MeioUpload - even though it's recently deprecated, it still works fine. It's what I currently use - I will probably switch to Upload Plugin soon.

Upload Plugin: https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload This is a new plugin, kind of intended to replace Meio Upload

CakePHP Media Plugin: https://github.com/bmcclure/CakePHP-Media-Plugin I haven't used this. It's apparently quite complex to get set up, but very good.